# ASP.NET MVC Visual Studio Virtual Directory not Showing up for Local IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, virtual

I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 community. I am having trouble finding my ASP.NET MVC sites in my IIS Manager after I create the virtual directory in the Properties window.

I originally was unable to view the IIS manager on my Windows 10 and had to search for "Windows Features" or "Turn Windows Features On or Off". I then selected the "Internet Information Services" checkbox.

I want to be able to host the site such that when I open it up from IIS Manager it should show up under the default web sites.

In the tutorial he was able to make the app do this by going to the Project's properties, the windows tab and check the Local IIS selection as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOoth.png)

Unfortunately I don't have his version of visual studio and all I see is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxA3d.png)

When I try to create the virtual directory anyway it doesn't show up in the IIS Manager. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial that you are following is of Visual Studio 2012 or prior as it is giving you development server option.

In your current version on the project properties => web screen there is a **Servers** section in that you can see a drop down that has value **IISEXPRESS** . Change it to **Local IIS** , Click on **Create Virtual Directory** next to it and this will create an application in your local IIS under the default web site (which ever is on port 80)) which you can see using IIS manager.

Make sure you are running visual studio in Administrator mode

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with the visual studio 2017 . Right click the VS tab and open it in admin mode , and it will show the option of local host under server dropdown.